# how to split each line of sentence into Array of string

Tags: java, android, arrays, flutter

```
String text = "test_123
check_1  123  
test_1
ASD@#$
qwer #$%^
test   1
this is book";
```

and turn it into a string array like:

```
{"test_123","check_1  123","test_1","ASD@#$","qwer #$%^","test   1","this is book"}
```

Comment: `text.split("\n")`

Comment: why does `test 1 this is book` only resolve to two Strings?

Comment: There is no common pattern in the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

The [split](https://www.baeldung.com/java-split-string) function is what will help you to achieve this, you'll have to **identify a pattern**, which is a [regular expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html), that work as the split rule.

From what I see the String **text** doesn't have an intuitive pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you want single elements, you can do this:

```
List<String> myList = List.of(text.split(" "));
```

However, like someone pointed out, there's no recognizable pattern in what you wanna do. You can try some weird regex inside the split but I doubt it'll work.

EDIT: If you add \n  at the end of each block of text/string it will work.  Example:

```
  String text = "test_123\n check_1 123\n test_1\n ASD@#$\n qwer #$%^\n test  1\n this is book\n";
    List<String> myList = List.of(text.split("\n"));
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

You can use the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* method, which uses a regular expression pattern as the argument.

The following should suffice in identifying the new-line delimiter.

```
\r\n?|\n
```

```java
String[] strings = text.split("\\r\\n?|\\n");
```

Additionally, you could use the *[BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html)* and *[StringReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/StringReader.html)* classes.

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(text));
String[] strings = reader.lines().toList().toArray(new String[0]);
reader.close();
```

Similarly, you could use the *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
scanner.useDelimiter("\\r\\n?|\\n");
String[] strings = scanner.tokens().toList().toArray(new String[0]);
scanner.close();
```

All of these methods will output the following.

```
[test_123, check_1  123, test_1, ASD@#$, qwer #$%^, test   1, this is book]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method. [Regular expressions](https://regex101.com/) can be used to define delimiter. For example:

```
    String newLine = "\n";
    
    String str = String.join(newLine, "test_123", 
    "check_1  123", 
    "test_1", 
    "ASD@#$", 
    "qwer #$%^", 
    "test   1", 
    "this is book");


    String[] splitted = str.split("\\s+|\\n+");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(splitted[i]);
    }
```